# NextJS/Strapi upload image to specific user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, strapi

I am working on an "Edit Profile" page on my app. I want the user to be able to change his profile picture. Here is how I try to do it:

```
const handleImageSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("files", image);
    formData.append("ref", "user");
    formData.append("refId", id);
    formData.append("field", "image");

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5090/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    });
    console.log(res);
    if (res.ok) {
      alert("image uploaded");
    }
  };
```

The image gets uploaded to the media library BUT the image doesn't get associated with the User. The user's info is set on "ref" and "refId" fields of the formData. I get a 200 "OK" response back, I guess that means the problem is somewhere in the formData.

If you need any more info to help me with this problem I'll update as soon as I see your replies, thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you certain the issue's not with the backend? Is the backend getting the right values from the body?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a 200 response back, everything seems to work fine but the image doesn't get associated with the user.. Still haven't found a solution.